# How much heat would an AMD FX-6350 emit if overclocked?

Tags: processor, desktop, cooling, heat-sink

I am planning to move an [Asus M5A78L-M/USB3](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/M5A78LMUSB3/specifications/) and its [FX-6350](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/fx-6350) CPU (default TDP 125W, max temp 61C) into a new chassis with a GeForce 1070 and a 680W power supply.

I am looking at a series of CPU coolers from BeQuiet! ranging from 125W to 250W.

If I really dial that motherboard up, What's the maximum power consumption of that CPU if highly overclocked, so I can determine how much cooling would be needed on that CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ASUS website](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/M5A78LMUSB3/specifications/), the board only supports a max of 140W so in theory your cooler doesn't need to be any better than that anyways.

However, that motherboard doesn't really have the VRMs required for significant and reliable overlocking. You *can* do it, but the lack of heat sinks on the VRMs and it only being a 4+1 design is likely going to hold you back from getting the most out of your CPU. Overclocking reviews for that board don't look so great.